# Could the Higgs mechanism also cause the flow of time?

Tags: time, higgs, symmetry-breaking

The Higgs mechanism gives mass to the standard model particles because it has a nonzero vacuum expectation value (vev). Now I read that there are models where the quadratic term in the Higgs potential in the very early universe flips sign such that the vev becomes zero, which would mean that no particles would have mass and they would all travel at the speed of light. But if all particles travel at the speed of light, then none of them would experience the flow of time, so in such a universe is it still possible to assign an observing reference frame which does experience the flow of time? Because I believe that even though a reference frame is a mathematical construction, it is implied that a massive observer is possible in this universe described by the reference frame, in order to experience the flow of time in this universe.

Answer (score 2):

Putting aside whether such an early Universe has hadrons, which would still be massive:

> if all particles travel at the speed of light, then none of them would experience the flow of time, so in such a universe is it still possible to assign an observing reference frame which does experience the flow of time?

Special relativity would still have reference frames related by boosts of less than $c$. This is just a comparison of coordinate systems that can be imposed on spacetime. How particles move through the spacetime is a separate issue.

> a massive observer is possible in this universe described by the reference frame

A reference frame *can* be an actual particle's rest frame, but it doesn't need this interpretation.